# Is there a way for a validator node to store relay chain db and parachain data in different partitions

Tags: parachain, database, validator

Is there a way to tell the validator node to store `db/full/parachains` on a different partition/location. Or is it safe to rsync it to a folder on another partition and then simlink it for a live validator?

Comment: This would be a good feature request on cumulus, but will eventually be solved by https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/issues/483

Answer (score 3):

The `db/full/parachains` will currently will be always put under the path of the main db. So, you could run your collator with `collator -- -d /some/path/for/db`. And then the parachains db will end in `/some/path/for/db/.../full/parachains`.

However, you can also do the symlink "trick" you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the parachain or relaychain database to another partition, and then make a soft symlink pointing to the new location in the original directory. This is a widely used trick in Khala mining community.